# Customize Document Card Preview PNP Modern Search

Tags: pnp, modern-pages

I am working on the layouts of the PnP modern search. I am using the document card to show the results. It has the preview enabled but I would like to make the preview box bigger with CSS.

Is this possible without having to build a new customized page results page? I would like to work with what is there.

https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/v3/search-parts/templating/#document-card